# Packing IOS App with Large Amount of Data

Tags: ios, app-store

How can I have the customer of an IOS app select and change selection data for use with an app?

I have an app that is designed to operate away from wifi. As such, it needs to carry its data around with it. This makes the data requirements rather large.

A base package is 25MB of data.  However, it is likely people who use this app would want as much as 1GB of data.

Is it possible to do selective data downloads and updates from the app store? 
How else could this be done

Answer (score 4):

> How can I have the customer of an iOS app select and change selection of data for use with an app?

Hard to say. It's not clear what you're talking about. Downloading data through an app is a well researched topic. You shouldn't have any trouble finding examples for downloading data to an app, here or elsewhere.

> Is it possible to do selective data downloads and updates from the app store? How else could this be done?

Again, its not 100% clear what you mean. I don't think you can use the app store to provide new data to users who downloaded your app, unless you're talking about a full app update that *comes* bundled with your new data set.

I worked on a project once that had to work offline, but also work with a very large data set as well as some mapping components. We required users to first download our app, then after authenticating, the app would automatically download a cache of data while connected to a WiFi hotspot. When the user was out of WiFi range the app would operate off the data set they downloaded and would operate normally. When they came back into range it would ping the server to find out if their data was stale. If it was stale it would download new data. The WiFi connection requirement ensured that they would have an optimal experience fetching the latest data.

Answer (score -1):

My thought is to create a menu in your app that lets the user select which "packages" of data they want to save to their device and run those downloads in the background when the user has an internet connection.